# drawBitmab(bitmap, null, rect, null) draw the bitmab below the specified rect

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, rect, ontouch

I am drawing many images to canvas using bitmap.. I want those bitmaps to be clickable.. so i draw them using rects so i can later check if the touched point is within those rects or not in OnTouch method..

but rect.contains(x,y) method always returns false if i touched anywhere on the bitmap.. while it returns true if the touched point was above the bitmap it self.. it seems like the bitmap and rect are sharing the same point (left, top) but the bitmap is drawn downward and the rect is drawn upward.. 
Can you enlighten me please?

here is my drawCanvas code:

```
private void drawCanvas(int position) {

    Bitmap icon9 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.camera_icon);
    Bitmap icon9Scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(icon9, 60, 60, true);
    icon9.recycle();
    rect9 = new Rect();
    rect9.set(15, 330, 15 + icon9Scaled.getWidth(), 330 + icon9Scaled.getHeight());
   // src9 = new Rect(0, 0, 60, 60);

    canvas.drawBitmap(icon9Scaled, null, rect9, null);

}
```

And here is my OnTouche method:

```
  @Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    //super.onTouchEvent(event);

    int x = (int) event.getX();
    int y = (int) event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
           // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Is TOUCHED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(rect9.contains(x,y))
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Icon 9 Is TOUCHED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("Is Icon 9 Touched", Boolean.toString(rect9.contains(x,y)));
            Log.d("Is Icon 9 Touched X", Integer.toString(x));
            Log.d("Is Icon 9 Touched Y", Integer.toString(y));
            break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: `Log.d` the value of `rect9` in `onTouch` and `drawCanvas` methods

Comment: D/Draw Canvas Left: 15
  D/Draw Canvas Top: 330  D/Draw Canvas Bottom: 390
   D/Draw Canvas Right: 75   D/Is Icon 9 Touched: true
 D/Is Icon 9 Touched X: 58
   D/Is Icon 9 Touched Y: 378  D/Is Icon 9 Touched: false
  D/Is Icon 9 Touched X: 54
   D/Is Icon 9 Touched Y: 447

Comment: just call `Log.d(TAG, "rect9: " + rect9);` in both methods and post the logcat with them and "Is Icon 9 Touched X/Y" logs

Comment: D/Rect 9 Draw: rect9: Rect(15, 330 - 75, 390)
      D/Rect 9 Touch: rect9: Rect(15, 330 - 75, 390)  D/Is Icon 9 Touched: true D/Is Icon 9 Touched X: 58 D/Is Icon 9 Touched Y: 378       D/Is Icon 9 Touched: false D/Is Icon 9 Touched X: 54 D/Is Icon 9 Touched Y: 447

Comment: btw `onTouch` where is it overriden?

Comment: it is overriden inside the activity

Comment: so you are calling `setOnTouchListener`? for what view?

Comment: I set it to the root layout of the activity.. it's relative layout

Comment: no wonder you are getting wrong X/Y positions, set it on your view where you are drawing the bitmaps

Comment: I don't have any views in my activity.. i am drawing a canvas that contains the bitmaps and adding this canvas to this relative layout..

Comment: so why do you need `RelativeLayout` at all??? and how are you adding a Canvas to anything???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100414/discussion-between-arwa-and-pskink).